# Как запретить форматирование конкретной строки или блока кода в Vue 3 SFC

Tags: vue3, eslint, prettier

Есть код:

```
const { getViewTasks, appendTimelineToViewTask, getCSVTaskEventLog } = useTaskService();
```

Я хочу его форматировать так(руками или с помощью Prettier):

```
const {
  getViewTasks,
  appendTimelineToViewTask,
  getCSVTaskEventLog
} = useTaskService();
```

Но вместо этого у меня форматируется так:

```
const { getViewTasks, appendTimelineToViewTask, getCSVTaskEventLog } =
  useTaskService();
```

Что вызывает ошибку линтера:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я знаю, что **Prettier** форматирует это так, потому что длинна строки ограничена.

Можно ли запретить форматировать строку или блок кода в **SFC** компонентах Vue 3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Документация по **prettier**: https://prettier.io/docs/en/ignore.html

Частичное решение проблемы, которое меня устроило(*setup TS SFC*):

```
if (
  // prettier-ignore
  // eslint-disable-next-line operator-linebreak
  task.state === VeryLongEnumName[SoToooooooooooLongEnumName] ||
  task.state === VeryLongEnumName[SoToooooooooooLongEnumName]
) {
  // ... do something
}
```

`eslint-disable-next-line operator-linebreak` - не обязательно, зависит от настройки **ESLint**.